# Installing Ubuntu on unbootable XP

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-xp

I hope you can help me because I'm getting really frustrated here. I've decided to turn to Ubuntu since I'm fed up with a BSOD my XP is giving me for a few days now, but I can't get through the install process. That BSOD I'm speaking of is happening during the Windows XP loading screen so I can't even get to the point where I type the password to access my PC. The only way I can get access to my computer is through safe mode and that's where I'm writing from right now.

1st I must say that my CD/DVD drive is broken, so I can't go that way. 2nd I've tried booting Ubuntu from USB pendrive, first by Unetbootin then by Universal USB Installer, but in both cases nothing happens - when I press boot from USB in BIOS, my PC is stuck on second loading screen (the one you have just before Windows XP logo loading screen).

So here's my question. Can I install Ubuntu from XP safe mode without using USB or CD? I know about the Live CD option and it would work perfectly fine but as I said before I can only work on safe mode and Live CD requests PC restart. And when I do that, I get BSOD before my current OS logs on. Please help me if you can, because I got to the point where I want to throw my computer out the window.

e/ sorry for any possible language mistakes

Comment: Do you see the BIOS before the BSOD?

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that your image on the USB is not installed/created correctly. I recommend doing that on another machine and testing it on that other machine.

For the part about installing Ubuntu through the Windows XP safe mode, even if it is possible, I can only see so many bad things coming from installing Ubuntu from inside Windows, even more from safe mode since it does not offer all hardware correctly detected or optimized with the drivers when loading Windows normally.

I recommendation is to do one thing at the time. First create the USB Ubuntu on another computer and test it that it boots correctly.

Make sure that on your PC, the Bios is correctly configured not only to boot from an USB as 1st choice but also that it allows booting from USB (Some BIOS give the option to boot from USB but have the option to actually boot from it somewhere else).

If you actually boot from the USB, simply follow instructions to be able to create a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows. From this point on, you can fix Windows through the Ubuntu desktop by checking it with fsck, looking for corrupted files, etc.

Comment: Ima keep trying with the USB method then. As far as my BIOS and USB boot, I know what you're talking about and I did that, so I'm pretty sure that is configured fine. It must be pendrive, so I'll check that on another PC and when I do that, I'll hit you up with the results. Is it also possible that my pendrive is unbootable, like "not compatible" or that's not the case? It's a not quite new Kingston DataTraveller 2GB.

Comment: Great quik. you might want to try another pendrive. One time I had problems with both of my pendrives and my wife had one spare one. It worked with her pendrive. My pendrives hated me. Am selling hating pendrives if you would like one ^^.

Comment: Hey, another question Luis. I've tried another pendrive, same thing. Also, I've tried to run some other OSes like Damn Small Linux and Slax, outcome is the same. Tommorow I'll see if they work on another PC. But should I first create a partition for the new OS before I boot from pendrive or is it to be done after booting, during an installation process? By the way I just found out about Ubuntu, Slax etc. like 2 days ago so it's all new to me.

Comment: @quik Hi buddy, the steps should be like this: 1. Create pendrive with Live ISO. 2. Boot from it. 3. After booting from pendrive you can create partitions, install OS, etc.. I recommend either using the USB Live Creator from Ubuntu from another ubuntu PC or using unetbootin or even using Live USB Creator. One of this 3 has to work on your case. Also try changing USB slot on the PC, just in case the slot has a problem. You can even install Ubuntu on another PC simply by taking the HDD out and putting it in another PC and doing the whole installation there, just in case the original pc has issue

Comment: I've done it! Freakin hell I've done it ;). I managed to boot it from USB, turns out there is this small little application called PEtoUSB and it helped me. Thanks Luis, you were very helpful. I might come here tommorow and seek guidance if I won't know how to install OS or such but the most important part is done. Its been almost like blood sweat & tears but fark it Im happy :D

Comment: Very happy it helped. Remember to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped or send it to hell it if didn't